# Maven runtime scope and cyclic dependency

Tags: maven, runtime, cyclic

I have two module A and B. Actualy B is plugin to A.
B depends on A in compile time.  A  NOT depend on B.
On A runtime I want to add B to classpath, so in A's pom.xml I add the following dependency

`pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my_group</groupId>
        <artifactId>my_Plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Maven  process  fail with cyclic dependency error

```
[ERROR] The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between 'Vertex{label='A'}' and 'Vertex{label='B'}' introduces to cycle in the graph B-->A-->B -> [Help 1]
```

[ERROR]

Why runtime dependency impact compile time ?

Comment: There's a good approach to arranging your build for this kind of project.  If you refactor out the code that is shared into another module (C), project B will no longer need to depend on A at compile time - A and B can both depend on C.  Then it's not a problem to have A depend on B at runtime.  A good way to think of this is to consider writing a library - a bunch of sharable code - and an application, which is a collection of assembled libraries.  An application project doesn't actually need to contain any code at all.

Comment: One solution is to add the cyclic dependency into a profile. That way Maven will not complain of the cyclic dependency when you build module A.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Conan and if possible extract your common code into a separate module in order to resolve the cyclicity. Normally, in such cases one would extract common interfaces and the core classes into a separate module which is extended by both modules which cause the cyclic dependency. You would then remove the direct dependencies on the modules which were initially in a cyclic state. Sometimes this is very hard to solve, but modularizing the code helps you figure out how to refactor your code so that it is easily re-usable.

Comment: The code of A is not under my responsibility, so I can't separate it.

Comment: Well, if it's code you or your company devised, this is the way to go.
If not -- based on your example and the little that you've told us, there is not other obvious solution.